# Rewriting JS, removing jQuery. $(this) trouble

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to rewrite this code into vanilla JS.

```
$('body')

    // change background image
    .on('click', '.bgtexture .list li', function() {

        var self = $(this);

        $('.bgtexture .active').removeClass('active');
        self.addClass('active');

        $('.start').css('background', 'url("img/masks/'+self.text()+'.png") repeat');

    })

    // change background image
    .on('click', '.bggradient .list li', function() {

        var self = $(this),
            color = self.text();

        $('.bggradient .active').removeClass('active');
        self.addClass('active');

        $('.gradient').attr('class','gradient').addClass(color);

    });
```

What I have so far is:

```
document.querySelector('.bgtexture .list li').addEventListener('click', function () {

    // what would $(this) be in vanilla js?
    var self = $(this);

});
```

What would $(this) be in vanilla js?

Comment: Try: https://github.com/eorroe/NodeList.js it'll make vanilla-js much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
var elemList=document.querySelectorAll(".bgtexture .list li");
for(var i=0, len=elemList.length; i < len; i++)
{
        elemList[i].addEventListener('click', function()
        {
                //Clicked element
                console.log(this);
        }, false);
}
```